# VoiceOver labels for lists (as data tables)

Tags: mobile, accessibility, native, voiceover

I have to display a list containing two pieces of information per cell: item quantity and expiration date.

On web, for a `<table>`, a screen reader would read each row item by saying the column title before the item value.
But on native mobile, there is no proper table component; we're talking about lists and cells.

For a given table:

```
╔════════╦═════════════════╗
║ amount ║ expiration_date ║
╠════════╬═════════════════╣
║      1 ║ 22/08/2009      ║
║     15 ║ 12/06/2016      ║
╚════════╩═════════════════╝
```

At the moment I have `"$amount item will expire on $date"` but nothing for headers.

I can't find proper guidelines for that particular case on WCAG (and its mobile addendum).

What would be the best labels for the header section and cells as well? Any hint on native specifics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the best labels for header section and cells as well

A good way to write labels may be found inside this [2019 WWDC video](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-19000.html#WritingGreatAccessibilityLabels) summary where the blind presenter explains the pitfalls to avoid and the best practices to use.

However, I think that `amount` and `expiration date` are appropriate as is to be well understood.

> Any hint on native specifics ?

Dealing with VoiceOver *(iOS screen reader)*, the system provides:

- An enum [`UIAccessibilityContainerType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/uiaccessibilitycontainertype?changes=latest_minor) including a data table type.
- A protocol [`UIAccessibilityContainerDataTable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycontainerdatatable?changes=latest_minor) to convey information about the contents of a table.
- A protocol [`UIAccessibilityContainerDataTableCell`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycontainerdatatablecell?changes=latest_minor) to provide the location of a cell in a table.